# Excel table order consistency with data connection refreshes

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have a data connection inserting data into COL A-H when it gets refreshed. I have a table COL A-T (because i extended the table that is generated by the data connection). I input values manually in COL I-T. When i refresh the table sometimes data will be added in between existing data rows. No matter which of the 3 options i choose under the table properties (Insert cells/Insert entire row/Overwrite) the order is always messed up because even when choosing -Insert entire row- the manually input rows do not shift up or down accordingly. Anyone knows an easy solution for this (don't care if its a workaround via GUI or a neat VBA code trick)?

I tried using the 3 different tables properties. i initially tried separating the tables, meaning the manual input is it's own table but it seems to not change anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.